# Model Validation in Asp.Net Core Doesnt Work

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, validation, web

my model validation doesnt work but every thing is ok I mean I have asp-net-validationin in view and my model have attributes and my submit button send the form with post method to index method in Home controller but the validation not working but the interesting part is that my login validation is work but my main form validation that has all the things that login form has not work I try every thing but no result. but I think the problem can be in the controller. I dont have any idea please help.

**Controller**

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Index(User user)
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
     return RedirectToAction("Index");
  }
     return View(user);
}
```

**User Model**

```
    public class User
    {
        [Key]
        public int LeadId { get; set; }

        [Display(Name ="name")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "please enter your name")]
        [MaxLength(50,ErrorMessage ="the max is 50")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "family")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "please enter your family")]
        [MaxLength(50,ErrorMessage = "the max is 50")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "email")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "please enter your email")]
        [MaxLength(100,ErrorMessage = "the max is 100")]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        public string EMailAddress1 { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "mobile")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "please enter your mobile")]
        [MaxLength(11,ErrorMessage = "the max is 11")]
        [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
        public string MobilePhone { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "please choose gender")]
        public int gender { get; set; }
    }
```

**view**

```
@model DataLayer.User

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "welcome to form";
    Layout = "/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";

}

<div class="preloader type-preloader d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
    <img src="/files/preloader/sdf.gif" alt="preloader" />
</div>
<div class="container">
    <form method="post" asp-action="Index" asp-controller="Home" name="myForm" id="myForm" class="box box1 col-lg-12 pb-3 pt-3 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12">
        <div class="row">
            @* Name *@
            <div class="form-group floating-label-group col-6 col-sm-12 col-xl-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                <i class="zmdi zmdi-account namedarkmode namedarkmode1 "></i>
                <input asp-for="FirstName" type="text" name="Name" class="Nameinput Nameinput1 name farsiinput jh" lang="fa" required autocomplete="off"  title="enter your name" maxlength="50" />
                <label asp-for="FirstName" class="floating-label-name floating-label-name1">name:</label><br />
                <span asp-validation-for="FirstName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            @* Family *@
            <div class="form-group  floating-label-group col-6 col-sm-12 col-xl-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                <i class="zmdi zmdi-account familydarkmode familydarkmode1 "></i>
                <input asp-for="LastName" type="text" name="Family" class="Familyinput Familyinput1 farsiinput family" lang="fa" required autocomplete="off" title="enter your family" maxlength="50" />
                <label asp-for="LastName" class="floating-label-family floating-label-family1">family:</label><br />
                <span asp-validation-for="LastName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>

        @* Email *@
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group floating-label-group col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-xl-12 col-lg-12">
                <i class="zmdi zmdi-email  emaildarkmode emaildarkmode1"></i>
                <input asp-for="EMailAddress1" type="email" name="Email" class="Emailinput Emailinput1" autocomplete="off" required title="enter your email" maxlength="100" />
                <label asp-for="EMailAddress1" class="floating-label-email floating-label-email1">email:</label>
                <span asp-validation-for="EMailAddress1" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        @* Mobile *@
        <div class="row">
            <div class="d-flex align-items-center align-items-baseline col-12">
                <div class="form-group floating-label-group">
                    <i class="zmdi zmdi-phone phonedarkmode phonedarkmode1"></i>
                    <input asp-for="MobilePhone" type="tel" name="Mobile" class="MobileInput  MobileInput1 farsiinput" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*?)\..*/g, '$1');" pattern="[0-9]{11}" lang="fa" dir="rtl" autocomplete="off" required title="enter your mobile" maxlength="11" />
                    <label asp-for="MobilePhone" class="floating-label-mobile floating-label-mobile1">mobile:</label><br />
                    <span asp-validation-for="MobilePhone" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>

                @* Male/Female *@
                <div class="form-group d-inline">
                    <div class="form-check custom-control custom-radio d-inline">
                        <input class="form-check-input MaleInput MaleInput1" type="radio" id="MaleRadio" name="Gender" />
                        <label class="form-check-label  custom-control-label cl maledarkmode maledarkmode1" for="MaleRadio"> man</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check custom-control custom-radio d-inline">
                        <input class="form-check-input FemaleInput FemaleInput1" type="radio" id="FemaleRadio" name="Gender" />
                        <label class="form-check-label  custom-control-label cl  femaledarkmode femaledarkmode1" for="FemaleRadio"> woman</label>
                        <small class="text-danger"></small>
                    </div>
                    <span asp-validation-for="gender"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        @* reCAPTCHA *@
        <div class="pt-2">
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-start form-group  recaptcha">
                <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LcZ05gbAAAAAHOBPJu3xvtCkQcB_mMQIVrxGmTd"></div>
            </div><br />
            <small class="text-danger recaptchaerror mb-6"></small>
        </div>

        @* button *@
        <div class="row pt-3 col-12">
            <button class="d-flex justify-content-start btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">
                <span class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm" role="status" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                enter
            </button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

**layout**

```
@model AdminContent
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fa">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>form</title>
    @* material design iconic *@
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/material-design-iconic-font/2.2.0/css/material-design-iconic-font.min.css">
    @* bootstrap *@
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    @* css *@
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" />
    @* fontawsome *@
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="">
</head>
<body class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">

    <header class="header">
        <nav class="navbar navbar1 d-flex align-items-baseline navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm">
            <div class="container navtop navtop1">
@*                <img  src="/files/AdminImages/@Model.IconImageName" />
*@                @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    <h1 class="navbar-brand navbar-brand1 d-inline text-secondary">@User.Identity.Name @ViewData["Title"]</h1>
                }
                else
                {
                    <h1 class="navbar-brand navbar-brand1 d-inline text-secondary">@ViewData["Title"]</h1>
                }
                @* start dark mode html *@
                <div class="container bn">
                    <div class="sun sun-logo">
                        <i class="fas fa-sun fonticon"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="moon moon-logo">
                        <i class="fas fa-moon fonticon"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
                @* end dark mode html *@
                @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    <i class="zmdi zmdi-power icon icon1"></i>
                    <a asp-action="Logout" asp-controller="Account" class="btn-link">exit</a>
                }
                else
                {

                    <i class="zmdi zmdi-account-box icon icon1 mb-7 ml-2"></i>
                    <a asp-action="Admin" asp-controller="Home" class="btn-link text text1 mnb mb-7 text-secondary">Admin</a>
                }
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <main class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-start align-items-start">
        @RenderBody()
    </main>
    @*    <script src="/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    *@
    <script src="/js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/index.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.3/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.3/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?hl=fa"></script>

    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe the ModelState is valid!

Comment: Can you post your `User` class too?

Comment: ok the model state can be valid but when the fields are empty and I submit the button the server validation not working and just client validation work because I have required in my input but the login form has too but the login form server validation work and the client validation message not show

Comment: have you added the asp net message for the fields into the view too

Comment: you mean in the span tag? or asp-validation-for?

Comment: can u post an example how looks one field in to the view

Comment: I removed the [tag:FluentValidation] tag from this question, since the code you posted does not have anything to do with the FluentValidation library. If you [edit] your question and include FluentValidation-specific code, feel free to add that tag back.

Comment: I add my view but I dont think there will be a problem

Comment: and what code have to be in the modelstate if { }

Comment: @sevada can you post all code on your layout page?

Comment: @PritomSarkar here you are .

Comment: @GoldenLion doesnt work.

Comment: @sevada  please make scripts are placed under the environment like development or production.

Comment: start a new project and then add your userViewModel class then test binding.  It should work out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

make sure to include your model name in the razor page.  This is how razor knows the ViewModel

```
@model UserViewModel
```

Startup.cs

```
  services.AddRazorPages();
```

RazorPage.cshtml

```
 <form method="post">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly"></div>
 </form>
```

Comment: not work and I had @model ------ in my view

Comment: My guess is key is failing to bind.  Remove all your annotations and see if post will bind when inspecting the userviewmodel

Comment: and let me say that one time I change  my controller codes and my server validation error messages was shown but not with clicking button  and it doesnt validate anything it just show the messages for that I think the problem can be in the controllers codes.